# How to output an array of unique items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm going over some online tuts and the subject is to put elements that are in an object into an array only if a certain property of the obj is unique. for this example that property would be "phoneNumber" the function to do that `uniquePush()` should work because it was on the website for a correct solution. my problem is outputting the array. I guess I don't quite understand how the return true or return false stuff works in terms of outputing the result. I know true and false are Booleans . I believe i tried something like

```
if(uniquePush(nameArr, person){
 then out put the obj.name
}
```

but that didn't work

here is the example from the tuts.

```
var person = {
        name:'bob', phoneNumber:1234,
        name:'joe', phoneNumber:123,
        name:'jack', phoneNumber:456,
        name:'duped1', phoneNumber:2345,
        name:'duped2', phoneNumber:2345
    }
    var nameArr =[];

    function uniquePush(arr, obj) {
      if(! ('phoneNumber' in obj)) {
        return false;
      }

      var unique = true;
      arr.forEach(function(element) {
        if(element.phoneNumber === obj.phoneNumber) {
          unique = false;
        }
      });

      if(unique) {
        arr.push(obj);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

I just want to have a pop up alert box that list the unique names like [bob, joe, jack] not duped1 or duped 2

I want to do that by doing something like this

```
uniquePush(nameArr, person);
alert(nameArr.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this approach you keep track of `phoneNumbers` by storing them in `numbers` array if they are not already there. If the number is there, using else branch you remove the previous occurrence of the same from `numbers` array.

```
var person = [
    { name: 'bob', phoneNumber: 1234 },
    { name: 'joe', phoneNumber: 123 },
    { name: 'jack', phoneNumber: 456 },
    { name: 'duped1', phoneNumber: 2345 },
    { name: 'duped2', phoneNumber: 2345 }
];

names = [];
numbers = [];

person.forEach(function(e){
    if(!(numbers.indexOf(e.phoneNumber) > -1)){
        numbers.push(e.phoneNumber);
        names.push(e.name);
    }else{
        numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(e.phoneNumber), 1) 
        names.splice(numbers.indexOf(e.phoneNumber), 1);    
    }
});
console.log(names);
```

**UPDATE** :

```
function uniquePush(arr, obj) {
    if(obj.phoneNumber === 'undefined') return false;
    unique = true;
    arr.forEach(function(e){
        if(e.phoneNumber === obj.phoneNumber){
            console.log('Nah');
            unique = false;
        }
    });
    if(unique){    
        arr.push(obj);
        console.log('Yep');
    }
}
```

You can test this function.

```
a = { name: "nodup", phoneNumber: 235 };
uniquePush(person,a);
console.log(person);
```

Person will have a new object `a` added at last, since it's unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this is a way to get the list. so good job. but I'm just concerned because the answer I gave was one of a bunch of answers that included returning true or false from funcs but it didn't show how to output counsel.log() like you did. I get confused on how to output info when a boolean is returned from a function like in my question. so I was hoping to see an example of that. I'm not trying to be picky. I just think that would help me. i cant show the link because you would need access to this http://www.codewars.com/kata/uniquepush-no-dupes/solutions?show-solutions=1

Comment: So you are checking that the new object pushed in person is unique or not?

Comment: i just want a list of the people with unique numbers. using an approach where Booleans are returned from functions. thanks

Comment: See the thing is if you need the list of unique names, you can use the above function. But if you need to push some unique object into `person` array , you can see the updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
     var person = [
           { name: 'bob', phoneNumber: 1234 },
    { name: 'joe', phoneNumber: 123 },
    { name: 'jack', phoneNumber: 456 },
    { name: 'duped1', phoneNumber: 2345 },
    { name: 'duped2', phoneNumber: 2345 }
    ];



    function uniquePush(arr, obj) {
        if (!('phoneNumber' in obj)) {
            return false;
        }

        var unique = true;
        arr.forEach(function (element) {
            if (element.phoneNumber === obj.phoneNumber) {
                unique = false;
            }
        });

        if (unique) {
            arr.push(obj);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how to output the names. I want to get a list like bob, joe, jack. Don't know how to do that